# Blockchain.info explorer doesn't recognize my hash

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, hash

Blockchain.info doesn't recognize my tx. Can someone explain this. My wallet is debited. The transaction is unconfirmed too.

Comment: Doesn't recognize it in what way? Their block explorer doesn't show the transaction? The wallet doesn't show it?

Comment: It means your TX never got in the mempool. Are you sure you're not using the testnet?

Comment: Why assume blockchain.info is correct.

Comment: My wallet is debited. Blockchain.info doesn't recognize the tx id. Not using trestnet. The day before Oct 5th a transaction went through, no problem. I am upgrading my node now, thought that be the problem and it is taking forever to sync. I still want this transaction to go through with coinbase. It's the only reason I'm still keeping my account open. But after this I probably won't use coinbase ever again.

Comment: @dave Does your TX show up on blockchain.com now?

Comment: No it does not. Why?